# Why is $\cos \pi x$ needed in $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(n)=\frac1{2i}\oint_{|x|=\infty}\frac{\cos \pi x}{\sin \pi x}g(x)\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to prove this sum formula:$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(n)=\frac1{2i}\oint_{|x|=\infty}\frac{\cos \pi x}{\sin \pi x}g(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$I do not understand why $\cos \pi x$ is needed here. This is because poles of $\sin \pi x$ are at $x=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you integrating over?

Comment: Hint: $(\sin \pi x)'=\pi\cos\pi x$.

Comment: Up to issue how should one take the limit, one has $$\frac{1}{\sin\pi x} = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-k)(\sin(\pi x)')|_{x=k}} = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\pi(x-k)}$$ The $\cos(\pi x)$ factor is there to get rid of the $(-1)^k$ factor in the residues.

Comment: @user302797, You changed the notations `\pi` `\infty` to `∞` and `π`. In my personal opinion, it is more suitable to use the former. Can you please explain why you use the latter?

Comment: @KemonoChen I don't know why you may find this problematic but these edits are meant to show more contents in the excerpt when viewing from the question list. Using Unicode is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user302797 I do appreciate your edits but I don't know whether using Unicode is OK.

Comment: @user302797 Using unicode to replace correct mathJAX markup is not acceptable. As the system won't know how to replace the unicode on different rendering engine and expression may not scale/style properly.

Comment: @achillehui MathJax does know how to render Unicode, which is nowhere deemed unacceptable. Could you justify your claim that the rendering might fail? Or even be able to provide any evidence?

Comment: @user302797 In general, I don't want to start a edit war. I'll flag this and let's mod decide.

Comment: The residue of $\frac\pi{\sin(\pi x)}$ at $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is $(-1)^n$. The residue of $\pi\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}$ at $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is $1$.

Comment: It is better to use MathJax to encode mathematical characters.  It is true that most browsers can render unicode, however, if the characters are encoded using MathJax, MathJax can manage effects like styling and sizing better.

Comment: Note that in `\large\piπ`: $\large\piπ$, the first is italic, which is in keeping with the other characters rendered in MathJax, like $abc$. Roman characters are usually used for operator names like $\sin(x)$ and $\log(x)$. See [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22630/%ce%b8-vs-theta-what-is-preferred-unicode-or-mathjax)